# Create a chrome bookmark to the Slack app

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, slack

Is it possible to create a bookmark / hyperlink in chrome that will link to a specific channel or chat in Slack?

I discovered that `slack://` will open the slack app, but simply taking the web interface link to the channel and replacing `http://` with `slack://` doesn't do the trick.

Is there any documentation for creating these links?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - it doesn't use `slack://`

```
https://slack.com/app_redirect?channel=C123ABC456
```

https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking